# How to use local information of checkbox and select in url_for?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am currently trying to make a website and am new to Flask and HTML.
I want to make a button that leads me to another site with information of local checkbox and selectbobx. 
Attached figure below is an example of this. I expect that url_for of "preview" button can pass information of the selectbox and the checkbox above as parameter.
It looks like this now:

```
<a class="button button-blue" href="{{ url_for('sample_gene', id=id) }}">Preview</a>
```

and I wonder how I can use checkbox and selectbox information into url_for as variable.
[Figure of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQq27.png)

Comment: code `{{...}}` is executed on sever and replaced by some text before it sends to browser - and browser doesn't have it. You will have to use JavaScript to add some value directly to HTML in browser. But if you have all in `<form method='GET'>` then it adds all values to url as `?name1=value1&name2=value2`. And if you use `method='POST'` then you get it in `request.form` and there is no need to add it to url

Comment: So I should cover whole thing with <form method='GET'> then I can have URL with `?` directly? I am using render_template and my current route looks like "http://172.16.55.231:1130/sample1/gene." How should I put information with `?` after this link name?

Comment: you don't have to add this manually  if you use `<form method="GET" action="url">` and `<button`> - browser will add ot automatically (to address which you have in `<form>`) when you click `<button>` inside `<form>`. And in function you get it in dictionary `request.args`. But if you want to use `<a>` then you will have to use JavaScript to add this data to `url` in `<a href="url">`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I tried to cover the button with `<form>`. However, it seems not to send information of other elements, like select box, to python. When I try to cover the whole page with `<form>`, it will automatically keep refreshing. How should I include information from other elements in the submission? Sorry if this question is silly : (

Comment: you have to put ALL elements in the same `<form>` to send them. But if you don't want to update full page (but only some part) then you have to use JavaScript. When you click <button> or <a> then all browsers send it and replace all page - it is standard behaviour and only using JavaScript you may change it.

Comment: Actually, I do want to update all information each time I click on the button. But I did not quite understand how should I cover them and send information only when I click on the button. Since when I cover the whole code with `<form>`, it just kept refreshing even I don't touch anything.

Comment: probably you have some JavaScript code which sends it automatically. But without full code it hard to say what makes problem.

Comment: Thank you co mush! I think I was able to solve this question with suggestion above!